# How much $\rm CO_2$ can you save by overfilling a SodaStream bottle?

Tags: homework-and-exercises, thermodynamics, pressure, water, physical-chemistry

For people who don't know what Sodastream is: SodaStream is a system where you can make your own soda at home using regular water and a CO2 cartridge. You put water in the special Sodastream bottle, connect it to the $\rm CO_2$ cartridge and pressurize to the target pressure. CO2 gets into the water and soda happens !

The SodaStream bottle has fill marker which still leaves a fair bit of empty volume. That seems to waste $\rm CO_2$ to me, since all this volume has to be compressed by the incoming $\rm CO_2$ to create the target pressure. So I have been overfilling my bottles before pressurizing and I was wondering how to run the numbers on that.

Assumptions:

1. Total bottle volume: 1010ml
2. Official target volume: 828ml
3. Overfilled volume: 972ml
4. Target pressure: 380 kPa (ambient = 100 kPa)

I can eyeball the amount of $\rm CO_2$ needed to build up the pressure from the difference in pressure and the required increase in mass inside the bottle

$$V_{official} = (1010ml - 828ml)\cdot \frac{380kPa}{100kPa} = 691 ml$$

$$V_{overfill} = (1010ml - 972ml)\cdot \frac{380kPa}{100kPa} = 144 ml $$

So that's a substantial savings. However, I can't figure out how to calculate how much $\rm CO_2$ actually gets into the water and if the overfilling makes a meaningful difference here.

Comment: The problem with this approach is that the target line is meant to give you the sweet spot for the amount of CO$_2$ dissolved into the solution at the pressure delivered by the device. If you reduce the headspace volume, then you are getting a small quantity of CO$_2$ contained in the headspace volume, and a proportionally smaller amount will be able to dissolve into solution before everything is equilibrated. If you overfill, you are likely making your pop more "flat" by default, though whether this is a good thing is entirely a matter of taste.

Comment: Why would the target line matter for the amount that's dissolved? I thought that would just be a function of pressure, which is determined by the valve in the filler regardless of how much water or gas is in the bottle. Once you remove the bottle from the filler the pressure goes back to ambient and any excess gas just goes back into the environment.